# PyTorch Lightning: What's the meaning of calling self?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Consider the following function:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self(x)
    loss = F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
    return loss
```

What's the meaning of calling `self` in this context?

How can self act as a callable anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling an object with `object()` is equivalent to calling the `__call__` method  of the given class, defined as usual with:

```
   def __call__(self):
```

So `self()` is equivalent to `obj.__call__` method of class object and  since it subclasses [`torch.nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module), which will invoke [`_call_impl`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1234), and eventually the [`forward` pass](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1184-L1185),